# "It would be appreciated if you can let us know when can we expect to receive the final payment" does this sound right?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, difference

> It would be appreciated if you can let us know when can we expect to receive the final payment

Does this sound right?

I have been using the sentence above whenever I am trying to be polite while chasing outstanding payments. However, I always feel it sounds off, especially  the 'When can we expect', shouldn't it be 'When we can expect' instead as I am not really asking a question?

Comment: Yes, it should be "when we can". Other than that, it sounds fine, if a little wordy.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it should be "when we can" instead of "when can we", and for the reason you gave. Other than that, I'd say it was mostly fine. I might, however, change:

> It would be appreciated if you can...

to:

> It would be appreciated if you could...

or:

> It would be appreciated if you would...

or even:

> Give me my money now, you thieving cad! Or else! Don't force me to come over there and introduce you to my Louisville slugger.

Comment: +1 for the ending.